# Issue during gulp minify the HTML

Tags: angularjs, gulp

When i try to minify the html using **gulp-htmlmin** im getting error in the following html line and it is because of **candidateProfile.cellPhone.$error.pattern**. is there any alter way to fix this.

```
<div class="styled-input js-form__error-wrap" ng-class"{'ng-has-error':candidateProfile.cellPhone.$error.pattern}">
                    <input type="tel" class="styled-input__input js-form__input" id="mobile" name="cellPhone" pattern ="[0-9]+" ng-model ="fields.cellPhone" required ng-class="{'has-value':!candidateProfile
.cellPhone.$error.required}">
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Im getting throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Parse Error: